# MySql query to find start and end of sequence blocks associated to specific user (not looking for gaps)

Tags: mysql, sequence

How would I go about to write a query that will use this data

```
ID  Timestamp            UID
1   2018-01-01 00:00:00  1
2   2018-01-01 00:00:00  1
3   2018-01-01 00:00:01  1
4   2018-01-01 00:00:01  2
5   2018-01-01 00:00:02  2
6   2018-01-01 00:01:00  2
7   2018-01-01 00:01:02  3
8   2018-01-01 00:02:00  3
9   2018-01-01 00:05:00  1
10  2018-01-01 00:05:01  1
11  2018-01-01 00:05:02  1
```

and return this:

```
ID1  ID2  Timestamp1           Timestamp2           UID
1    3    2018-01-01 00:00:00  2018-01-01 00:00:01  1
4    6    2018-01-01 00:00:01  2018-01-01 00:01:00  2
7    8    2018-01-01 00:01:02  2018-01-01 00:02:00  3
9    11   2018-01-01 00:05:00  2018-01-01 00:05:02  1
```

Meaning, i need to get first and last timestamp and first and last ID of each sequence block belonging to same UID (ordered by starting ID, as there is no overlapping)
There will be no ID gaps in blocks as this is a table with permanent undeletable data

Thanks

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning a block number is a way to go. The below query does so using a variable in the sub query.

```
select min(id) minid, max(id) maxid ,blocknumber, min(timestamp) mints, max(timestamp) maxts ,uid
from
(
select t.id,t.Timestamp,t.UID,
        if( t.uid <> @p,@bn:=@bn+1,@bn:=@bn) blocknumber,
        @p:=t.uid p
from t
cross join(select @bn:=0,@p:=0) r
order by t.id,t.uid
) a
group by uid,blocknumber
order by min(timestamp)
;
+-------+-------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| minid | maxid | blocknumber | mints               | maxts               | uid  |
+-------+-------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
|     1 |     3 | 1           | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2018-01-01 00:00:01 |    1 |
|     4 |     6 | 2           | 2018-01-01 00:00:01 | 2018-01-01 00:01:00 |    2 |
|     7 |     8 | 3           | 2018-01-01 00:01:02 | 2018-01-01 00:02:00 |    3 |
|     9 |    11 | 4           | 2018-01-01 00:05:00 | 2018-01-01 00:05:02 |    1 |
+-------+-------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
4 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

Comment: table t doesn't exist

Comment: Disregard the previous comment - I had a stupid moment

Comment: Can I ask for an explanation of the query?
I'd like to know the how and the why (copy pasting code is stupid if i don't understand it, so i'd like to understand)

Comment: Disregard that too. I figured out what's what.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
            SELECT a.*, b.* FROM 
            (SELECT MAX(timestamp) as amax, id, uid FROM `test` GROUP by uid) as a,
            (SELECT MIN(timestamp) as amin, id, uid FROM `test` GROUP by uid) as b
```

Please remove test by your table name.

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in an error
**Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column**
Works if id is removed, but returns unmatched data